# Automatically add new number page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.content').append('<div class="Box"></div>')
});
```

```css
.wrap
{
  position:relative;
}

.content
{
  width:200px;
  height:330px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  
 }
.Box
{
  width:180px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:grey;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-90px;
  margin-top:5px;
  top:5px;
}
.numberPage
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid #666;
  position:relative;
  top:-30px;
  left:170px;
}
.numberPage span
{
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:3px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="Box">
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="numberPage">
  <span>1</span>
 </div>
</div>

<button>Add new box</button>
```

Hello,

I have one question about javascript I think. How add automatically new number page after added 5 boxes in <.content> e.g. like 1 2 3...10. I think it should create new  with current page number after prpend fifth grey box, but I don't know how I can do it. 
I will be grateful for any advices

Comment: Are you talking about pagination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
//chek if  content height is biger than the sum of box heiht inclding the nmpage height and magin
  if($('.content').height()>(($('.Box').height()+10)*($('.Box').length+1))){
    $('.content').append('<div class="Box"></div>');
  }else{
    var currentPage=parseInt($('.numberPage .active').html());
    PagesFiled[currentPage]=true;
    currentPage++;
    $('.numberPage .active').removeClass('active');
 $('.numberPage').append('<span class="active">'+currentPage+'</span>');
    //clear boxes and add in next page
    $('.content').empty();
    $('.content').append('<div class="Box"></div>');
  }
});

var PagesFiled={};
```

```css
.wrap
{
  position:relative;
}

.content
{
  width:200px;
  height:330px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  
 }
.Box
{
  width:180px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:grey;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-90px;
  margin-top:5px;
  top:5px;
}
.numberPage
{
  display:flex;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  
  position:relative;
  top:-30px;
  right: -7px;
}
.numberPage span
{
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:3px;
  }
 .numberPage .active{
   border: 1px solid;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="Box">
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="numberPage">
  <span class='active'>1</span>
 </div>
</div>

<button>Add new box</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, it is big progress for my beginner adventure with js,  but I looking solution when number pages will be inline like 1,2,3...10 and I will be back to previous page

Comment: Have edited the code to push filed pages in 'PagesFiled' object;
add click event to $('.Box') and go back to previous page if its filed. Hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for help, I will try do it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    if ($('.content .Box').length == 5) {
      $('.content .Box').remove();
      var number = parseInt($('.numberPage span').text()) + 1;
      $('.numberPage span').html(number);
    }
    $('.content').append('<div class="Box"></div>')
});
```

```css
.wrap
{
  position:relative;
}

.content
{
  width:200px;
  height:330px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  
 }
.Box
{
  width:180px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:grey;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-90px;
  margin-top:5px;
  top:5px;
}
.numberPage
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid #666;
  position:relative;
  top:-30px;
  left:170px;
}
.numberPage span
{
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:3px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="Box">
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="numberPage">
  <span>1</span>
 </div>
</div>

<button>Add new box</button>
```

Comment: Thank, its big step for me, but I would like to prepend numberPage inline because what if I will back to previous page? I is this possible make it in frontend or this thing need do in backend?

Comment: This can be done with JS but you have to make content boxes with the previously appended child so when you will go to the previous page you can see them. Also once page will be loaded it will be lost. If you want to keep you have to store the current status.

Answer (score 1):

try this one. adding the current page no. + 1 on every button click.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var counter = $('.numberPage span').text();
    $('.content').append('<div class="Box"></div>');
 
    if($('.content .Box').length == 6){
      $('.content .Box').remove();
       counter = parseInt(counter) + 1;
        $('.numberPage span').text(counter);
    }
   
});
```

```css
.wrap
{
  position:relative;
}

.content
{
  width:200px;
  height:330px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  
 }
.Box
{
  width:180px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:grey;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-90px;
  margin-top:5px;
  top:5px;
}
.numberPage
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid #666;
  position:relative;
  top:-30px;
  left:170px;
}
.numberPage span
{
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:3px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="Box">
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="numberPage">
  <span>1</span>
 </div>
</div>

<button>Add new box</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't want paginate "grey box" but .content after add fifth box

Comment: Thanks, great job, but is possible to make page number inline? Because what if I would like back to previous page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for this

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.content').append('<div class="Box"></div>')
    $('.numberPage').append('<span>'+($('.numberPage span').length + 1 )+'</span>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```js
t = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.content').append('<div class="Box"></div>');
    t++;
  if (t%5 === 0) {
    $('.wrap').append('<div class="numberPage"><span>'+t+'</span></div>');
  
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap
{
  position:relative;
}

.content
{
  width:200px;
  height:330px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  
 }
.Box
{
  width:180px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:grey;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-90px;
  margin-top:5px;
  top:5px;
}
.numberPage
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid #666;
  position:relative;
  top:-30px;
  left:170px;
}
.numberPage span
{
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:3px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="Box">
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="numberPage">
  <span>1</span>
 </div>
</div>

<button>Add new box</button>
```